# Insert NewChidldActivity in-Between MainActivity and FirstChildAcvitity And Change Default ChildActivity to the NewChildActivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, manifest

Fellow Friends,

thank you all for your usual support.

I have developed an an examination app with login functionality.

Previously, the app had 3 Activities (MainActivity, WelcomeScreenActivity and QuestionsAcvitity). This app is working perfectly.

However, when the user logs in from the MainActivity, the WelcomeScreenActivity shows.
But I need to INSERT another activity (PROFILE_ACTIVITY) between the MainActivity and the WelcomeScreenActivity so that, when the user logs in successfully, the app will display the user's PROFILEACTIVITY.

Pictures below the page

### **Previous Code before the new ProfileActivity**

**MainActivity.java code**

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            if (!responseData.equals( "User Not Found" )) {
                message = "Welcome";
                data = responseData;//store the user id from the server in data
                //Bundle bundle = new Bundle();//bundle the message and parse it to the next activity
                //bundle.putString("dispMsg", message);//bundle the message using the variable dispMsg
                //intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
                statusBar.setText(message);
            } else {
                message = responseData;//"Incorrect Username or Password. Try again!";
                statusBar.setText(message);
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
```

**DisplayWelcomeScreenActivity.java code**
This activity displays after a successful login.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_welcome_screen);

    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        intent = getIntent();
}
```

To pass from this WelcomeActivity to the next QuestionsActivity, the code below does that on buttonclick() event

```
public void courseClicked(View v) {

        String course = "";
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CSS_342_Questions.class);
        int qNum = 0;

       switch (v.getId()){
           case R.id.buttonCSS342:
               course = "CSS 342";
               qNum=1;
               break;
           case R.id.buttonCSS352:
               course = "CSS 352";
               qNum=1;
               break;
           case R.id.buttonCSS354:
               course = "CSS 354";
               qNum=1;
               break;
           case R.id.buttonCSS356:
               course = "CSS 356";
               qNum=1;
               break;
           case R.id.buttonCSS381:
               course = "CSS 381";
               qNum=1;
               break;
           case R.id.buttonPCR362:
               course = "PCR 362";
               qNum=1;
               break;
       }
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("dispCode", course);
        bundle.putInt("qNum", qNum);
        //bundle.putString("dispMsg", "Welcome");
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The QuestionsActivity gets displayed using the code below.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_css_342__questions);

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        intent = getIntent();
        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        showCode = bundle.getString("dispCode");
        qNum = bundle.getInt("qNum");
}
```

This code below is the Manifest xml that links the 3 activities together for proper navigation.

**AndroidManifest.XML code**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.examinationportal">

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".DisplayWelcomeScreen"
            android:label="@string/welcome_screen_title"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

            <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".CSS_342_Questions"
            android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
            android:label="@string/question_screen"
            android:parentActivityName=".DisplayWelcomeScreen">

            <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".DisplayWelcomeScreen" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterUserActivity"
            android:label="@string/new_user_form"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

            <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Now, I want to insert a new activity (ProfileActivity) between the MainActivity and the DisplayScreenActivity.

I have changed the AndroidManifest xml code below.
The app is crashing. The LogCat shows the line where the app is crashing  `**StartActivity(intent)**` in MainActivity.java; line 153

### **The Code After the new Activity**

The MainActivity code still remains the same.

**The new AndroidManifest.xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.examinationportal">

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ProfileAcvitity"
            android:label="@string/student_profile"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

            <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterUserActivity"
            android:label="@string/new_user_form"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

            <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**New ProfileActivity.java code**

```
public class ProfileAcvitity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_acvitity);

        intent = getIntent();
    }
```

### LOGCAT INFORMATION

```
04-25 13:53:33.680 14789-14789/com.example.examinationportal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.examinationportal, PID: 14789
                                                                               android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.examinationportal/com.example.examinationportal.DisplayWelcomeScreen}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4034)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3986)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4325)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4293)
                                                                                   at com.example.examinationportal.MainActivity$GetText.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:153)
                                                                                   at com.example.examinationportal.MainActivity$GetText.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:83)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Thank you.

[image][image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is clearly saying `DisplayWelcomeScreen` not defined in Manifest file. So please define `DisplayWelcomeScreen` Activity in Manifest.

Comment: Chief, you have not completely read thru my post before you got to the logcat info. I said that I am inserting a new activity before DisplayWelcomeActivity. That's why I have removed DisplayWelcomeActivity and put ProfileActivity instead, which is now throwing a crash error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name=".DisplayWelcomeScreen"
            android:label="@string/student_welcome"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

            <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />

        </activity>
```

Adding those lines in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file will solve your problem.

Comment: Dear friend, I said that I am inserting a new activity before DisplayWelcomeActivity. That's why I have removed DisplayWelcomeActivity and put ProfileActivity instead, which is now throwing a crash error. The code you have placed above will only move to DisplayWelcomeActivity instead of ProfileActivity. That's not the activity I want to display.